# gradient updates on space of matrices

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, lie-groups, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I have an optimization problem in which I need to perform gradient descent in a space of matrices. I'd like to understand how to perform the gradient updates while remaining in the space. If my matrices formed a Lie group, I know there can be ways to follow geodesics, but I don't think this is the case.

My matrices are *complex symmetric* and they can be decomposed as:
$$
A = U D U^T
$$
where $U$ is some unitary matrix (note there's a transpose on the right, not a conjugate transpose) and where $D$ is a diagonal matrix of real values in the interval $[-1,1]$ (extremes excluded). Also, note that the diagonal of $D$ does not contain the eigenvalues, the decomposition above is just a way of constructing $A$.

If I perform gradient updates naively as $A \leftarrow A - \epsilon\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^*}$ I eventually break the condition that the elements of $D$ should remain bounded between -1 and 1.

1. Do the $A$ matrices form a known group?
2. How should I perform the gradient updates?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the objective? For example, can you write it as a convex program? It looks like an interior point method would be useful, but it’s quite difficult to tell without more details.

Comment: Oh I wish it were a convex program! It's an optimization of quantum circuits, I have managed to compute gradients backward from the loss function all the way to $A$, but there are other things at play. If A were, say, orthogonal or unitary I could use geodesic walks on the Lie group. But I don't think the A matrices form a group...
I could, clearly, use the relation $A=UDU^T$ and back propagate one more step to $U$ and $D$ and optimize those, but if I could avoid that it would be better...

Comment: Well, you decomposition looks to be the Takagi’s factorization. So your constraint on $D$ is a constraint on the singular values of $A$. I don’t have much to say except that SDPs and interior point methods seem relevant.

Comment: Where is the optimization problem?